# How to compare one value from a list of lists to another value from a list of lists in Python

Tags: python, list

i'm quite new to python but i'm trying to compare two list of lists in Python 2.7.

```
testlist = [['asd', 7],['bla', 5],['hi', 3]]
reflist =  [[1, 576 ],[2, 832],[3, 123],[4, 412],[5, 948],[6, 14],[7, 2],[8, 76],[9, 79]]
```

so the desired output would be this:

```
testlist = [['asd', 7, 2],['bla', 5, 948],['hi', 3, 123]]
```

by appending the second value of each list in reflist only if the first value matches the second value of each list in testlist ... maybe something like this ?

```
for l in testlist:
    if l[1] in b[0] for b in reflist:
        l.append(b[1])
```

Many thanks !

Comment: Does it work? Please also indent your code correctly.

Comment: Moreover, are these comparison values guaranteed to be unique in `reflist`?

Comment: yes the comparison values are unique IDs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert the `reflist` a dictionary using dictionary comprehension, and the lookup would be easy and faster, like this

```
d = {item1:item2 for item1, item2 in reflist}
print [item + [d.get(item[1])] for item in testlist]
# [['asd', 7, 2], ['bla', 5, 948], ['hi', 3, 123]]
```

Even simpler, the dictionary can be constructed with `dict` function, like this

```
d = dict(reflist)
```

If you want to use the basic, but inefficient method, then you can do it like this

```
for item in testlist:
    for number1, number2 in reflist:
        if number1 == item[1]:
            item.append(number2)
            break

print testlist
# [['asd', 7, 2], ['bla', 5, 948], ['hi', 3, 123]]
```

This changes the list in-place. If you don't want to do that, you can do

```
result = []
for item in testlist:
    temp = item[:]
    for number1, number2 in reflist:
        if number1 == item[1]:
            temp.append(number2)
            result.append(temp)
            break
    else:
        result.append(temp)

print result
# [['asd', 7, 2], ['bla', 5, 948], ['hi', 3, 123]]
```